# How to know if CrystalReport Preview is closed

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have this VB code to create a Crystal Reports preview :

```
Public Sub ShowReport(ByRef R As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass, ByVal Page As Byte, ByVal Grup As Boolean, Optional ByVal Rate As Integer = 0)
        Dim formula As String = R.RecordSelectionFormula
        R.DataSourceConnections(0).SetConnection(PrmServer(), PrmDatabase(), True)
        R.RecordSelectionFormula = formula
        Dim f As New RptPreview
        f.Crw.ReportSource = R

        f.Tag = Grup

        f.Show()

    End Sub
```

I want to know when user closes the report preview so that I will do some operations. Is there a function like `f.PreviewClosed`? Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't going to modify the report itself, or if the user will not need to view it again after the preview, then you could place a CrystalReportViewer object into a new Form.  At this point you can either open the form as modal and perform your operations after its closed, or capture the Form's Close event.  There are some issues with scope to consider though.  The report itself will be disposed when the form is closed.